# How to escape quotes in a MySQL statement in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am creating a Class that is parsing an array of 10 `[fileNames / tableNames]` from an FTP site and loading them in MySQL. I am using  `LOAD DATA INFILE` Below is the code block. This is all working fine with the exception being when I try to add `ENCLOSED BY '"'` When I add that param to the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement I am unable to figure out how to escape the single quote in Java. I have several large files that have text values that are enclosed by quotes and without using `ENCLOSED BY '"'` they fail.

```
public int DatabaseEntry(String sql, String[]fileArray, int updFlag) {
 for(int i =0; i < fileArray.length; i++)
  {
     parseString = fileArray[i];
        String[] tokens = parseString.split("/");
        filetoEat = tokens[0];
        tableName = tokens[1];          

    final String sql1 = "LOAD DATA INFILE" +  filetoEat  + "INTO TABLE iber_stage." + tableName + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY',' LINES TERMINATED BY'\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";
    try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    st = con.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery(sql1);

    if (rs.toString() != null) {//get first result
        returnMsg = rs.toString();
        System.out.println(returnMsg);   //Debug info       
        updFlag = 0;
    }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Create.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        updFlag = 1;

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Create.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        updFlag = 1;
```

I am looking for this final statement

```
"LOAD DATA INFILE" +  filetoEat  + "INTO TABLE iber_stage." + tableName + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY'\n' IGNORE 1 LINES";
```

Like I mentioned, this works well and is fast however, If there is a better way to loop through an array of filenames and tablenames and create a prepared statement please advise.

Thanks,
Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Statement, use PreparedStatment.

Look at this document: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

It will escape your query.

To escape the single quote in the ENCLOSED BY param try this

```
String str = " ENCLOSED BY \"\" [REST OF THE STRING]"
```

Comment: I still can't create a String for LOAD DATA INFILE using ENCLOSED BY '"' to use in a Prepared Statement. Its not the statement that is failing. When I add the ENCLOSED BY '"' it fails to compile due to an Invalid Character Constant. It all runs fine with or without a Prepared Statement when I omit the ENCLOSED BY '"' param.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but if you want a String with double quotes, you should do this: String str = " ENCLOUSED BY \"\" [REST OF THE STRING]"